# Get value of Telerik GridCheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadgGid on which I have implemented filtering capability. There is a column which contains a GridCheckBoxColumn. If it is checked, all active records are displayed and if unchecked, all inactive records are displayed. I have attached a sample imagefor reference.

[image]

How can I know whether the checkbox is selected or not?

```
 foreach (GridDataItem item in radgrid.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chk = item["Active"].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
..
}
```

The above does not work because it returns whether the checkbox in the MasterTable is selected or not. If the table has 3 records, it iterates through the 3 records and if their isActive column is not checked it returns false. But on top of it resides the checkbox which I can either check or uncheck. I need this checkbox's value. If it is checked, all active records are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method i believe with radgrid which allows you to get a list of selectedItems in the Mastergrid

try

GridItemCollection selectedItems = rdGrid.SelectedItems;

then loop through and get selected